# Universal Enveloping Algebra of $\mathfrak{gl}(n,\Bbb R)$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I am just learning about universal enveloping algebras, and I am wondering about the following.

> **Question:** Is the universal enveloping algebras of $\mathfrak{gl}(n,\Bbb R)$ just $\mathfrak{gl}(n,\Bbb R)$ itself?

It is an associative algebra with matrix multiplication. But I am not sure that it satisfies the universal property.

Given an $\Bbb R$-algebra $A$ and a Lie algebra homomorphism
$$\varphi:\mathfrak{gl}(n,\Bbb R)\to A$$
we must show that it is also an $\Bbb R$-algebra homomorphism. That is
$$\varphi([X,Y])=\varphi(X)\varphi(Y)-\varphi(Y)\varphi(X),\quad\forall X,Y\quad\implies\quad \varphi(XY)=\varphi(X)\varphi(Y),\quad\forall X,Y.$$
I am not sure this is true.

Comment: note that the universal enveloping algebra of a lie algebra will typically be infinite dimensional as an $\mathbb{R}$-vector space

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not true. For example, consider the trace operator
$$\mathrm{tr}:\mathfrak{gl}(n,\Bbb R)\to \Bbb R.$$
Then,
$$\mathrm{tr}([X,Y])=\mathrm{tr}(XY)-\mathrm{tr}(YX)=0=\mathrm{tr}(X)\mathrm{tr}(Y)-\mathrm{tr}(Y)\mathrm{tr}(X).$$
However, it is **not** true in general that
$$\mathrm{tr}(XY)=\mathrm{tr}(X)\mathrm{tr}(Y).$$